# Reconfigure a Windows Embedded 7 device to allow changes to be saved

Tags: shutdown, windows-embedded-7

We use a samsung screen with a built in pc running windows embedded 7.  When we set this up a year ago, we change some settings to prevent the computer having any changes saved when it was shut down.

It has worked well... but now we need to make some changes and cannot remember or find the instructions on how to turn this feature off... can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

probably you have the writefilters set.  Use their manager sto disable them or to force to write by using the "commit" option.

Remember that enabling/disabling the writefilter only happens at reboot.  So after disabling the filter you have to reboot the system before you start making changes.

These are the manager:
EWF: ewfmgr  (protects a complete partition)
FBWF: fbwfmgr (protects only certain folders and files).
UWF was not in Wimdows Embedded 7 (it's new in WE8)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably configured one of this write filters:

```
Universal Write Filter (UWF)
Enhanced Write Filter (EWF)
File-Based Write Filter (FBWF)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but only configured mine a month ago and still couldn't remember. Log in as administrator. In the icon tray in the lower right, expand the icon tray and scroll over the icons. One is EWF. Right click and select Enable EWF. There will be a dialog screen with several options. Click commit changes to save your changes.